# Show each row that is a duplicate

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with contains duplicate rows.For ex This is my table

```
 OriginalUrl                           NewUrl
/blog                                 /blog
es/blog                               es/blog
blog                                  blog
```

Now I would like to get the duplicates as follows

Output:

```
    OriginalUrl                           NewUrl
    /blog                                 /blog
    blog                                  blog
```

Thanks to "Zohar Peled" I have achieved most of it through this code http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c96cc/5.

But when I add blog without (/) I would even that as a duplicate as shown above.But this isn't happening with this code.So could anyone help me to achieve this

Comment: Can you clearly define what is "duplicates" for your case?

Comment: blog or http://gaming.corsair.com/blog or http://www.corsair.com/blog these 3 are duplicates.As only the url changes but not the name of the product

Comment: why 300r is not duplicate?

Comment: I have to check only after the '/'

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: Please edit your question once again and **describe *exactly* what you mean by duplicates.** I've tested my answer on your new sample data and got back the same results as your desired output, however if you add a record where the OldUrl is `www.google.com/whatever` this will obviously will not count as a duplicate according to my suggested solution. **So**, instead of making us work so hard, please spend a few more minutes to describe your criteria for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Final update

After yet another goal post shifting, I've updated my CTE again.
This is the final update since even if you are going to change your demands again I've had enough.
Please take my advice for future questions:

- Defind the problem as well as you can.
- Provide the most accurate table structure and sample data as ddl+dml.
  Don't link to sqlfiddle as it suffers from a lot of downtime.
- Provide the most accurate expected output
- Show your efforts to solve the problem.

Here is the last updated CTE, everything else remains as it was in the last update. [sqlfiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c96cc/5)

```
;WITH CTE AS (

SELECT OriginalUrl, 
       NewUrl,
       RIGHT(OriginalUrl, 
             LEN(OriginalUrl) - 
                 CHARINDEX('/', OriginalUrl,
                     CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%://%/%', OriginalUrl) > 0 THEN
                         PATINDEX('%://%/%', OriginalUrl)+3
                     ELSE
                        0
                     END
                 )+1
             ) As Product
FROM MyTable 
)
```

### Update

Updated sample data (again....)

```
-- Create sample table and data. 
-- DDL
create table MyTable (
  OriginalUrl varchar(50),
  NewUrl varchar(50)
)
-- DML
  insert into MyTable VALUES 
('/blog', '/blog'),
('http://gaming.corsair.com/blog', 'http://gaming.corsair.com/blog'),
('http://www.corsair.com/blog', 'http://www.corsair.com/blog'),
('http://www.corsair.com/es/blog', 'http://www.corsair.com/es/blog')
```

I've updated the CTE to include in 'Product' everything from the last '/' char, so product for the first 3 rows is now `/blog`, and for the last one it's `/es/blog`. so everything after the protocol and domain parts of the URL is considered a product now. Note - this also should apply to `https` and any other protocol.

```
;WITH CTE AS (

SELECT OriginalUrl, 
       NewUrl,
       RIGHT(OriginalUrl, 
             LEN(OriginalUrl) - 
                 CHARINDEX('/', OriginalUrl,
                     PATINDEX('%://%', OriginalUrl)+3 -- get the location right after '://' 
                 )+1 -- get the location right after the first / after the patindex
             ) As Product
FROM MyTable 
)
```

My query on the new CTE remain as it was in the last attempt:

```
SELECT T1.OriginalUrl, T1.NewUrl,T2.Product 
FROM CTE T1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Product
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY Product 
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) T2 ON(T1.Product = T2.Product)
```

Here is the output:

```
OriginalUrl                       NewUrl                            Product
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
/blog                             /blog                             /blog
http://gaming.corsair.com/blog    http://gaming.corsair.com/blog    /blog
http://www.corsair.com/blog       http://www.corsair.com/blog       /blog
```

[You can play with it yourself on sqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a4510/6)

### Earlier versions

So, by duplicates you mean all rows that have the same string after the last `/` in OriginalUrl column?
If so, you might want to try this:

```
-- Create sample table and data. 
-- DDL
create table MyTable (
  OriginalUrl varchar(50),
  NewUrl varchar(50)
)
-- DML
  insert into MyTable VALUES 
('/blog', '/en-us/blog'),
('/blog', '/en-us/blog'),
('http://www.corsair.com/blog', 'http://www.corsair.com/blog'),
('http://gaming.corsair.com/blog', 'http://gaming.corsair.com/blog'),
('blablabla/blog', 'yadayada/blog'),
('I don''t see what is wrong with this/Answer', 'It seems to be working/Fine'),
('Unless my/Answer', 'assumes duplicates as something else then/you'),
('300r', '300r')
```

**Note:** You should use this way to provide sample data when asking questions about sql.
This way we can copy your DDL + DML to sqlfiddle or our own environments and actually test the answers we give.

I've Used a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to insulate the last word after the last / in your sample data,
so that I will only have to write the RIGHT expression once.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT OriginalUrl, 
        NewUrl,
        RIGHT(OriginalUrl, CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/', OriginalUrl) > 0 THEN
                               CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(OriginalUrl))-1
                           ELSE 
                               LEN(OriginalUrl)
                           END) As Product
FROM MyTable 
)

SELECT DISTINCT T1.OriginalUrl, T1.NewUrl,T1.Product 
FROM CTE T1 
INNER JOIN CTE T2
ON(T1.Product = T2.Product)
WHERE T1.OriginalUrl <> T2.OriginalUrl
```

**Update**
Using the same CTE, try this:

```
SELECT T1.OriginalUrl, T1.NewUrl,T2.Product 
FROM CTE T1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Product
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY Product 
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
) T2 ON(T1.Product = T2.Product)
```

Results:

```
    OriginalUrl                                        NewUrl                                             Product
    -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
    I don't see what is wrong with this/Answer         It seems to be working/Fine                        Answer
    Unless my/Answer                                   assumes duplicates as something else then/you      Answer
    /blog                                              /en-us/blog                                        blog
    /blog                                              /en-us/blog                                        blog
    http://www.corsair.com/blog                        http://www.corsair.com/blog                        blog
    http://gaming.corsair.com/blog                     http://gaming.corsair.com/blog                     blog
    blablabla/blog                                     yadayada/blog                                      blog
```

Comment: Tq for the answer, but it is not showing blog if it is there twice,I mean if only product blog appears twice

Comment: I don't know what you mean, then. I've tested it on my environment and the result was exactly as your expected result. I would have provided a link to sqlfiddle but it's currently not working.

Comment: Along with that do insert one more time the '/blog' and see the result.It is displaying blog once even if present twice

Comment: No, showing you the result's pane so that you can see what i got and tell me what's wrong with this answer. (I've added one more /blog and 2 /answer urls to the sample data, seems to be working fine to me)

Comment: See my last edit. You should have included that in your sample data in the first place. It would have saved both of us some time and effort.

Comment: I wanted to show as duplicates if it contains http://gaming.corsair.com, http://www.corsair.com before blog.But it is also showing duplicate if it is /es/blog also

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c96cc/1. When I remove the http:// part for the last value.it is showing in the o/p but it shouldn't show if the url is removed too

Comment: Well what do you expect if you keep changing the terms? Each time I've answered your question I tested my solution according to your sample data, and gave you a solution that returned your expected result. Every time I've done that you just added one more row to your sample data that breaks my suggested solution. Should you have bothered to correctly and exactly specify your question in the first place, I'm sure you would already have a working solution in your hands right now. You make is very frustrating to try and help you.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is what I have to do through the code.I haven't done with any evil instinctions. Thx for everything what you have done.But help me to fix this last issue Plz.

Comment: Just change this row `)+1` to this `)` and it will not have the last `/` as a part of the product, making `/blog` and `blog` the same product. You should have play with it yourself for a few minutes and figured that one out yourself. [See fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72b78/4)